# SQL query for display of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL. I want to write a query where I have to select and display all records where the integer value is not between 5000 and 12000.

Comment: what is integer value, column name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, Its working for me

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE price NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 12000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Number
from Table1
where Number < 5000
  or Number > 12000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

[SQL Between](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Answer (score -1):

It would help to have table structures but this will give you everything but between those numbers.

```
Where Int < 5000
AND Int > 12000
```

If you want to include those numbers

```
Where Int <= 5000
AND Int >= 12000
```